# How to change application settings from another application [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, settings

I have created two application in VB.NET, In 1st application there are some settings stored, I want to change that settings from another application. How can I do that. ??

Comment: Ask yourself if that is really something you want to do. I would say no, you don't. That's what data stores like databases are for. You could open the settings file and edit it's xml but not if the other application is open and using it. This idea will fail, try another way.

Comment: That would depend on where those settings are stored. Perhaps you could provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem.

Comment: Have a look at this image : https://ibb.co/hRpeHn